# How to get xml element having namespace using java smooks and freemarker

Tags: freemarker, smooks

I am new to "smooks and freemarker".I want access elements in xml document.I am getting this exception while acessing xml element.I am  sending my code.

```
Exception:-
------------

 For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), but this evaluated to a sequence+hash (wrapper: f.e.dom.NodeListModel):
    ==> employee["first_name"]  [in template "free-marker-template" at line 1, column 84]

----
Tip: This XML query result can't be used as string because for that it had to contain exactly 1 XML node, but it contains 0 nodes. That is, the constructing XML query has found no matches.
----
----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${employee["first_name"]}  [in template "free-marker-template" at line 1, column 82]

----
Java stack trace (for programmers):
----
freemarker.core.NonStringException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]
    at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToString(EvalUtil.java:381)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.evalAndCoerceToString(Expression.java:82)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:40)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:312)

The following are versions
java version : "1.7.0_45"
freemarker   : 2.3.22
smooks       : 1.6


javacode:-
-----------
package test;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.milyn.Smooks;
import org.milyn.SmooksException;
import org.milyn.container.ExecutionContext;
import org.milyn.event.report.HtmlReportGenerator;
import org.milyn.io.StreamUtils;
import org.milyn.payload.StringResult;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class SmooksExample {
    public SmooksExample() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    protected static void runSmooksNew() throws IOException, SAXException, SmooksException {

        try {
            Long stTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(stTime + "==" + new Date());
            Writer xmlResultWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Files\\SmookExample\\output_sax.dat")));
            transCustomerCSV(new File("C:\\Files\\emp_namespace.xml"), xmlResultWriter);
            Long edTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(edTime + "==" + (edTime-stTime) + "===="+ new Date());
            String times = String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(edTime-stTime),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(edTime-stTime) - 
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(edTime-stTime))
                );
            System.out.println(times);
        } finally {
            //smooks.close();
        }
    }
    public static void transCustomerCSV(File csvSourceReader, Writer xmlResultWriter) throws IOException, SAXException {
        File f = new File("C:/TEMPLATES/smooks-config.xml");
        URI u = f.toURI();
        Smooks smooks = new Smooks(u.getPath());
        ExecutionContext ec = smooks.createExecutionContext();
        smooks.filterSource(ec, new StreamSource(csvSourceReader), new StreamResult(xmlResultWriter));
    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, SmooksException {
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        System.out.println("==============Message In==============");
        SmooksExample.runSmooksNew();
        System.out.println("======================================\n");
    }
}


Smooks-config.xml
--------------------
<smooks-resource-list xmlns:ftl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/freemarker-1.1.xsd" xmlns:core="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/smooks-core-1.3.xsd" xmlns:jb="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/javabean-1.2.xsd" xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd">
  <params>
    <param name="stream.filter.type">SAX</param>
    <param name="default.serialization.on">false</param>
  </params>
  <core:namespaces>
    <core:namespace prefix="empl" uri="http://www.example.com/employees"/>
  </core:namespaces>
  <resource-config selector="employee,first_name">
    <resource>org.milyn.delivery.DomModelCreator</resource>
  </resource-config>
  <ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="first_name">
    <ftl:template><!--<#ftl ns_prefixes={"empl":"http://www.example.com/employees"}>${employee["@id"]},${employee["first_name"]}-->
    </ftl:template>
  </ftl:freemarker>
</smooks-resource-list>

sample data xml file name:  emp_namespace.xml:-
--------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<empl:employees xmlns:empl="http://www.example.com/employees">
     <empl:employee id="1">
         <empl:first_name>Bill</empl:first_name>
         <empl:last_name>Adams</empl:last_name>
         <empl:age>25</empl:age>
         <empl:hire_date>12-06-1995</empl:hire_date>
         <empl:title>Java programmer</empl:title>
        <empl:DateCreated>
            <empl:Year>1980</empl:Year>
            <empl:Month>01</empl:Month>
            <empl:Day>01</empl:Day>
        </empl:DateCreated>
        <empl:DateCompleted>
            <empl:Year>1981</empl:Year>
            <empl:Month>02</empl:Month>
            <empl:Day>02</empl:Day>
        </empl:DateCompleted>
     </empl:employee>
     <empl:employee id="2">
         <empl:first_name>Mary</empl:first_name>
         <empl:last_name>Jones</empl:last_name>
         <empl:age>32</empl:age>
         <empl:hire_date>22-09-2001</empl:hire_date>
         <empl:title>Sales manager</empl:title>
         <empl:DateCreated>
            <empl:Year>1982</empl:Year>
            <empl:Month>03</empl:Month>
            <empl:Day>03</empl:Day>
        </empl:DateCreated>
        <empl:DateCompleted>
            <empl:Year>1983</empl:Year>
            <empl:Month>04</empl:Month>
            <empl:Day>04</empl:Day>
        </empl:DateCompleted>
     </empl:employee>
</empl:employees>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `ns_prefixes` you specify the namespace prefixes used in the FTL, which is independent of the namespace prefixes used in the XML. FreeMarker doesn't care what the actual prefix was in the XML, it only cares about the namespace URL. So since you have declared the `empl` prefix, you had to use it the FTL too (like `empl\:employee.empl\:first_name` - kind of awkward, as the `:` has to be escaped). But since you mostly access that single namespace, I recommend declaring that namespace URL to be the default:

```
<#ftl ns_prefixes={"D": "http://www.example.com/employees"}>
```

And then you don't have to add a prefix:

```
${employee.first_name}
```

(Note that here I assume that in Smooks the data-model root is the document element. I don't know if that's true, but anyway, as far as XML namespaces are concerned, this is how it works. Also, you have multiple `employee`-s in the XML so that above won't work because of multiple matches, but that's another topic.)